# BSC transaction without fees

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ether, bsc

Can anyone understand how this guy sent the transaction without fees

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x96d769ddb8725ded79eaf89e1a240948aa4b036e8188b8678298c19851407fdc

Comment: Can you rephrase that as a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Transaction with zero gas price are usually put in a block by miners (or validators in case of BSC) directly, or by miners that have some kind of arrangement with the transaction sender. Otherwise, market conditions (most miners choose transactions with highest gasPrice to be included in their blocks) prevent a 0 gas priced transaction to be mined.

So most likely, the sender address is one of the addresses belonging to the validator of the block 13352409, or to their business partner.

Comment: Thank you so much Petr, I understand now.